# Truncate all database tables with Hibernate and Spring Boot

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, integration-testing, junit5

I need to truncate all database tables after each test. Is there a way to do so or at least a database agnostic way to get all table names so that they can be truncated.

Any other alternatives are welcome. But keep in mind `@Transactional` and `@Rollback` will not help as I'm dealing with integration tests which fire http request on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're going to struggle to truncate tables in a simple, database-agnostic way. For example, what do you do about foreign key constraints? Some DBs will let you just truncate the tables in the correct order, leaving you with the problem of how to define that order. But if I recall correctly, some won't let you truncate tables with foreign key constraints at all, even if empty. Then you need to use some DB-specific DDL to disable the constraints, or worse, drop and recreate them.

You are also ruling out parallelising your integration tests if you take this approach.

I've always found a better approach is to make each test clear up just the data that it created. For example, for your `create` API, you may be able to register a listener that records the IDs of all created entities in your test code, then on teardown you can just reverse iterate this list of IDs, calling your `delete` API. The downside of this approach is that you may need to implement APIs that your application doesn't actually need, just to support the tests. However these can then be disabled by a flag on deployment to production.

Answer (score 0):

I read this property from a text file and add the 2 hibernate properties in the if statement which rebuilds the database every time I execute my project, perhaps this can help you?

```
if (environment.getProperty("dbReset").compareTo("ON") == 0)
{
    properties.put("hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
}
```

Comment: As the application context is not restarted after each test this does not help.

Comment: Gotcha, as answered below i'd say the best approach would be to somehow keep track of the data created by your tests and delete it in reverse order.  This does ultimately create code your application might never need but it will make your life a whole lot easier.